# In Python, what would be the purpose of else:continue in a try..except block?

Tags: python

I'm reading some source code which contains a `try`..`except` block with an `else: continue` statement. It is somewhat similar to the following:

```
numerator = float(1)
denominator = float(2)

def do_divisions(numerator=numerator, denominator=denominator):
    for _ in range(10):
        try:
            fraction = numerator / denominator
            print "{numerator}/{denominator} = {fraction}".format(numerator=numerator, denominator=denominator, fraction=fraction)
            denominator -= 1
        except ZeroDivisionError:
            print "You cannot divide by zero!"
            return False
        else:
            continue

result = do_divisions()
```

I'm struggling to understand what the `else: continue` statement does. As I understand from https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/controlflow.html, the `else` clause gets executed if no exception occurs, and `continue` continues with the next iteration of the loop. However, is this not what Python would do anyways?

Comment: No need for it here.

Comment: I think you are right: `else: continue` does not do any extra functionality here. I think this block was inserted just as a **placeholder**, for any future additions of code to be executed if no exception has been raised.

Comment: If `continue` is the last instruction of a loop then clearly it has to be redundant. Agree, with @SergiiShcherbak that is is likely a placeholder, although I think `pass` would be a better placeholder

Comment: It continues to next loop. Since there is no extra code to be executed after this statement, it's simply redundant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, yes, `else: continue` is redundant and it could be left out.

But if there were more code after the `else:` block, it would not be redundant because the `continue` statement would cause that code to be skipped. This is a reason that a programmer might want to use `else: continue`. For example, if the code in the `try:` block completes without an exception, then nothing more needs to be done about the current item in the loop, but if it does raise an exception, the program needs to catch that exception and do something else to clean up after it. That cleanup code could be placed after the `else:` block.

Answer (score 1):

`else` is a part of the `try` clause syntax. It is the opposite of `except`. It means "do this if no exception happens". It has nothing to do with `if-else` (also, it has an unfortunate and confusing name. even some of the creators of python mention that, but it is too difficult to change it now)

The difference is that code in `else` executes *only* if no exception happens, while code following will execute regardless. In the code example you mention, it does nothing, as the loop would continue anyway!

Comment: I realize this difference, but the question remains what `else: continue` does in this code example?

Comment: sorry, my mistake, edited the answer. it does nothing in your case, `continue` would happen anyway..